# Telescoping linear actuator

Tags: motor, actuator, cnc

I need to find a linear actuator that can extend to multiple times it's length. I am going to be fixing the actuator horizontally and it will carry a light vertical load.

So far I have thought of using something similar to the mechanism in a scissor lift. However, this is intended for a CNC application and needs high precision, and I'm not sure a scissor lift design would be rigid enough vertically when place horizontal. The system will eventually be feedback controlled so some give can be tolerated.

Is there something other than a scissor lift design that would be better suited to this application?

Comment: Can you not use a ball screw actuator?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* TimTheEnchanter, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: You said, "intended for a CNC application and needs high precision, and I'm not sure a scissor design would be rigid enough." You then *immediately* say, "some give can be tolerated." Pick one. What is your *tolerance*? You can have some give *in what dimension*? I can Google "telescoping linear actuator" and find results. I don't understand how those aren't useful to you. Ultimately, though, you appear to have a set of requirements and seem to want help designing a solution. You're more than welcome to join us in [chat] and ask, but those questions are off-topic for the site.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a linear motor like this one we use on our wheelchair(to push the seat up):

https://youtu.be/3lb_8nmy90c

Thouse motors are calles lamba motors and are made from phoenix mecano.

The have smaller and bigger one, the new version of the wheelchair has 1 stronger one.

Comment: It appears that the actuators used in the video are the standard type that only extend to twice their length. I need a specialized actuator that can extend to many times it's length.